# Transponer Df con valores nulos en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tras importar un archivo .xlsx a Pandas, quiero transponer los datos de la columna 'Ruta' para convertirlos en fila de manera que:

```
df= 
     Origen   Destino  Indice Ruta
0    1        8        1      nan 
1    nan      nan      nan    19
2    nan      nan      nan    20   
3    nan      nan      nan    21
4    1        9        1      nan 
5    nan      nan      nan    56
6    nan      nan      nan    40   
7    nan      nan      nan    9       
8    nan      nan      nan    26
9    3        7        1      nan 
10   nan      nan      nan    18
11   nan      nan      nan    25
```

quede algo como esto:

```
df= 
    Origen   Destino  Indice Unnamed1 Unnamed2 Unnamed3 Unnamed4
0   1        8        1      19       20       21       nan
1   1        9        1      56       40       9        26
2   3        7        1      18       25       nan      nan
```

Answer (score 0):

La función pd.pivote_table(...), pero por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, ¿tendrías tantas columnas UnnamedX, como valores tiene la columna Ruta, después de una fila con Origen, Destino y Indice rellenas de valores numéricos? Te hago la pregunta para tener claro que es lo que necesitas exactamente.

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu responder sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: @ivanao, intentaba responder a la pregunta mediante un comentario, pero me indica que no tengo suficiente reputación, para escribir un comentario directamente a la pregunta del usuario. En este caso, si me deja responderte a ti en un comentario... Por lo que no entiendo la diferencia. Además, he intentado arrojar un poco de luz a su duda, indicando que función podría utilizar para conseguir su propósito. Gracias por la aclración inicial.